# Mashed-up emojis stored in a Postgres database not returned as single emoji using Python 3.9 with psycopg3. For example ‍ returned \u200d

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, unicode, psycopg3

I am reading text containing emojis from a Postgres 13 database. Turns out that my Python/psycopg query does not decode/return the text as I would expect.

### Via Postgres `psql` client

- Within `postgres:13` container

  select description from profile WHERE id = 123

Result is as expected!

```
️‍ and ‍‍⚕️
```

### Via Python 3.9 with [psycopg3](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/connections.html#psycopg.ConnectionInfo) adapter

- Within a `python:3.9` container
- same query as above

The result is not correctly retuned - fails to combine

```
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> profiles = cur.fetchone()
>>> profiles[0]

️\u200d and \u200d\u200d⚕️
```

Connection object says it is using `utf-8`

```
>>> conn.info.encoding
'utf-8'
```

### What am I missing here?

Any idea what I should be looking for?

Many thanks for your thoughts in advance, much appreciated!
Eu

Comment: Could You display response from database as hex (`encode('utf-32')`)?

Comment: Hi @Michas many thanks - 

txt.encode('utf-32')

b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\xf3\xf3\x01\x00\x0f\xfe\x00\x00\r \x00\x00\x08\xf3\x01\x00 \x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00i\xf4\x01\x00\r \x00\x00\xbb\xf4\x01\x00i\xf4\x01\x00\r \x00\x00

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe 
many thanks - this is a possibility. A reason why I mentioned it was within the  python  container. I will run more tests (save data to host) and compare with psql client output there

Comment: https://emojipedia.org/emoji-sequence/

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, just as you said it was the shell in the python:3.9 container. 
I saved the text to a file and viewed it in the host shell. All mashed-up emojis displayed correctly. Happy for you to add your answer here and I shall accept it. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emojis consist of several characters, and the shell you are using does not know how to display them in the way you want.

JosefZ posted a link for more details: https://emojipedia.org/emoji-sequence/

Answer (score 1):

I have analysed string by raw bytes (provided in comment). The `profiles[0]` variable holds the valid string. The problem is only in the way the string is displayed, the more advanced emojis (using ZWJ `\u200d`) are not supported.

To get preview, You can dump the content to a text file and open in in a web browser.